# Who was the leak in Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the TNG episode, [Preemptive Strike](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Preemptive_Strike_(episode)), we learn that a someone in Starfleet has been leaking information to the Maquis.

From the [script](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/276.htm):

> SANTOS: Macias. I've checked with my **sources** at Starfleet. Her story's
>   true.
>
> MACIAS: I was sure it was. Kalita, she'll stay with you until we can
>   find her a room.

Has source's identity been established?

Comment: in S2 of DS9 we meet Calvin Hudson, a Starfleet officer who is, shall we say, sympathetic w/ the Maquis. The two episodes aired within a month of each other, thus it's possible that could have been Hudson. Also - we aren't exactly sure just what they are checking up w/ re: Ro. She isn't really telling them anything at that point that wouldn't be part of an official service record so the source could have been something like a simple database hack

Comment: @NKCampbell - Ah! interesting.

Comment: @NKCampbell - This poses another question, one I brought up in the comment section of another post, but Starfleet computer security is pretty weak. In some episodes, they remove panels, cross a few wires, or remove a chip, and they're inside whatever system they were trying to hack.